# Function On Click Messing Up my jQuery Slideshow

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a jQuery slideshow from scratch. I was able to successfully create HTML structure of the slideshow (positioning the slide divs on top of one another).

I then successfully coded some jQuery to only show the first slide and only the "next" button.

You can see it working up to this point here: http://jsfiddle.net/chLNj/

I then tried to add functionality by manipulating the divs when clicking on the next or previous arrows. For some reason, though, my code breaks the jQuery script and all the divs just show.

You can see that error here: http://jsfiddle.net/chLNj/2/

I can't for the life of me figure out what I've done wrong (I am a novice at jQuery, to be honest). If anyone could help me figure out what I'm doing wrong, it would be greatly appreciated!

All my code is in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/chLNj/2/ but here it is again:

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    font-family: 'Abel', sans-serif;
    font-size: 17px;
    line-height: 23px;
    }

*, *:before, *:after {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    }

.container {
    width: 500px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin: 20px auto;
    padding: 15px;
    }

.postContainer {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

.postContainer h1 {
    font-family: 'Medula One', cursive;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 46px;
    font-size: 52px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

/************SLIDESHOW************/

.slideshow {
    background-color: #DEDFCC;
    width: 100%;
    height: 320px;
    position: relative;
    }

.slideContainer {
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    }

.slide {
    width: 60%;
    height: 300px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #C9B7B7;
    }

.slideMiddle {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.slide img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    }

.slideInfo {
    width: 40%;
    height: 80%;
    float: right;
    padding: 10px;
    }

.slideNav {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #C9B7B7;
    color:  #DEDFCC;
    }

.prevSlide {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    }

.nextSlide {
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
    }

.slideCredit {
    width: 40%;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 12px;
    }

.fix {
    clear: both;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="postContainer">
    <h1>Harry Styles</h1>
    <p>Harry Styles is known as One Direction&#8217;s resident heartthrob. Check out this slideshow showcasing precisely why!</p>

                <div class="slideshow">


                <div class="slideContainer">
                  <div class="slide">
                    <span class="slideMiddle"></span><img src="http://onedirectionconnection.com/jquery/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/tumblr_inline_n3zn2ypCPu1qbf6hn.gif">
                  </div>
                  <div class="slideInfo">
                    <p class="slideCaption">
                      He's just a cheeky fella, isn't he?                   </p>
                    <p class="slideCredit">
                      Tumblr                    </p>
                  </div> <!--slideInfo end-->
                  <div class="fix"></div>
                </div> <!--slideContainer end-->
               <!--end if each if-->


                <div class="slideContainer">
                  <div class="slide">
                    <span class="slideMiddle"></span><img src="http://onedirectionconnection.com/jquery/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Harry-Styles.jpg">
                  </div>
                  <div class="slideInfo">
                    <p class="slideCaption">
                      Does this need an explanation?                    </p>
                    <p class="slideCredit">
                      ODC                   </p>
                  </div> <!--slideInfo end-->
                  <div class="fix"></div>
                </div> <!--slideContainer end-->
               <!--end if each if-->


                <div class="slideContainer">
                  <div class="slide">
                    <span class="slideMiddle"></span><img src="http://onedirectionconnection.com/jquery/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/article-2561301-1B94054200000578-549_634x642.jpg">
                  </div>
                  <div class="slideInfo">
                    <p class="slideCaption">
                      His glorious, glorious hair.                  </p>
                    <p class="slideCredit">
                      Google                    </p>
                  </div> <!--slideInfo end-->
                  <div class="fix"></div>
                </div> <!--slideContainer end-->
               <!--end if each if-->


                <div class="slideContainer">
                  <div class="slide">
                    <span class="slideMiddle"></span><img src="http://onedirectionconnection.com/jquery/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/article-2521940-19F5CE0900000578-42_634x738.jpg">
                  </div>
                  <div class="slideInfo">
                    <p class="slideCaption">
                      But he can also wear whatever the hell he wants and STILL look snazzy doing so.                   </p>
                    <p class="slideCredit">
                      Splash                    </p>
                  </div> <!--slideInfo end-->
                  <div class="fix"></div>
                </div> <!--slideContainer end-->
               <!--end if each if-->


                <div class="slideContainer">
                  <div class="slide">
                    <span class="slideMiddle"></span><img src="http://onedirectionconnection.com/jquery/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Harry-Styles-in-Alexander-McQueen-BRIT-Awards-2014-600x902.jpg">
                  </div>
                  <div class="slideInfo">
                    <p class="slideCaption">
                      He can rock the latest fashions and look snazzy doing it!                 </p>
                    <p class="slideCredit">
                      Getty                 </p>
                  </div> <!--slideInfo end-->
                  <div class="fix"></div>
                </div> <!--slideContainer end-->
               <!--end if each if-->
             <!--end each-->
        </div><!--slideshow end-->
        <div class="slideNav">
            <div class="prevSlide">
              <i class="fa fa-chevron-left fa-2x"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="nextSlide">
              <i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-2x"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="fix"></div>
        </div>
     <!--end if-->
  </div> <!--postContainer end-->



                    </div>
```

And finally, jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".slideshow").each(function() {
    var slideshow = $(this);
    var slides = $(slideshow).children().length;
    var n = 1;

    $(slideshow).children().hide();

    if(n == 1){
        $(".prevSlide").hide();
    }

    $(slideshow).children(':nth-child(' + n + ')').show();

    $('.nextSlide').click(function (){
        if(n == 1){
            n++;
            $(".prevSlide").show();
            $(".nextSlide").show();
            $(slideshow).children().hide();
            $(slideshow).children(':nth-child(' + n + ')').show();
            console.log(n);
        }else if(n > 1) {
            n++;
            $(slideshow).children().hide();
            $(slideshow).children(':nth-child(' + n + ')').show();
            console.log(n);
            if(n == slides){
                $(".prevSlide").show();
                $(".nextSlide").hide();
            }
        }
    }
    $('.prevSlide').click(function (){
        if(n == slides) {
            n--;
            $(".prevSlide").show();
            $(".nextSlide").show();
            $(slideshow).children().hide();
            $(slideshow).children(':nth-child(' + n + ')').show();
            console.log(n);
        }else if(n > 1) {
            n--;
            $(slideshow).children().hide();
            $(slideshow).children(':nth-child(' + n + ')').show();
            console.log(n);
            if(n == 1){
                $(".prevSlide").show();
                $(".nextSlide").hide();
            }
        }
    }


  }); // each 1 end

}); // ready method end
```

Comment: FYI, once you've done `$(this)` and stored the value in `slideshow`, you don't have to do `$(slideshow)`; you can just do `slideshow.children()` and such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a `);` after the final `}` of your `.nextSlide` click handler.

Comment: Thank you so much! That fixed it... It's usually something so simple. And thank you for the tip about storing variables. I'll check your answer as soon as StackOverflow lets me!